# Creating tfb file in Python Toolbox?

Tags: arcpy, parameters, python-toolbox

**What tool does:**

Simply creates tbf file from raster extent.

**What is the problem:**

I ran toolbox in ArcMap 10.5.1 and ArcGIS Pro 2.2.4.

When I run it as standalone script it is working just fine.

I am not new to Python nor Python Toolboxes, but today:

1) I received an error which I never encountered before (error shown below)

2) when I declare `rasters = arcpy.ListRasters('tif')`, list of rasters is empty.

**Error code:**

> Running script Tool...
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 54, in execute
>     File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line 527, in set_
>       self[env] = val
>     File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line 587, in **setitem**
>       ret_ = setattr(self._gp, item, value)
>       enter code here
>
> RuntimeError: Object: Error in accessing environment 
>    Failed to execute (Tool).

**Tool code below:**

```
import arcpy
import os

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
        .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "tfb file generator"
        self.alias = ""

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [Tool]


class Tool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "Generating tbf files"
        self.description = ""
        self.canRunInBackground = True

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""
        # Pierwszy parametr
        inside = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="In workspace",
            name="in_gdb",
            datatype="DEWorkspace",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")

        p = [inside]
        return p

    def isLicensed(self):
        """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
        validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
        has been changed."""
        return

    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
        parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
        return

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""
        arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

        arcpy.env.workspace = parameters[0].valueAsText
        output = parameters[0].valueAsText
        rasters = arcpy.ListRasters('*.tif')


        i=1
        for ras in rasters:

            arcpy.AddMessage('Working on raster nr:  {0} of {1} '.format(i, len(rasters)))
            f = arcpy.Raster(ras).extent

            north = f.YMax
            west = f.XMin
            south = f.YMin
            east = f.XMax

            i+= 1
            ras_split=ras.split('.')[0]

            with open(os.path.join(output,'{0}.tfb'.format(ras_split)), "w+") as text_file:
                text_file.write('north={0}\n'.format(north))
                text_file.write('west={0}\n'.format(west))
                text_file.write('south={0}\n'.format(south))
                text_file.write('east={0}'.format(east))

        return
```

---

Fixed all mistakes - tool fully working.

Comment: What is a tfb (or is it tbf) file?

Comment: Tbh, I know only my client need to generate hundreds of tfb files for his tiffs. He is using them for this purpose I guess: https://www.rolands.com/jtls/j_designs/JTLS-2015-12485.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arcpy.env.workspace = parameters[0]` should be `arcpy.env.workspace = parameters[0].valueAsText`.

You are setting the workspace to a `Parameter` object, not a string, see [Accessing parameters within a Python toolbox](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/accessing-parameters-within-a-python-toolbox.htm)

Your `rasters = arcpy.ListRasters('tif')` will find only rasters called exactly `"tif"`.  If you want to find rasters with a `.tif` file extension, use `rasters = arcpy.ListRasters('*.tif')`